# Utilizando groupby em pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

boa tarde.

Não tenho muita habilidade com Python, estou com algumas dúvidas.
Quem puder me ajudar, desde ja agradeço.

Abri meu arquivo csv no python da seguinte maneira:

```
import pandas as pd

caminhoArquivo = r'\\Desktop\Base\dias.csv'

baseDados = pd.read_csv(caminhoArquivo,sep=';',decimal=',',encoding='latin-1')
```

Exemplo do Arquivo:

```
Index  |  Nome  |  Dia
  0    | Pedro  |   3
  1    | Pedro  |   3
  2    | Pedro  |   24
  3    | Antonio|   24
  4    | Antonio|   24
  5    | Antonio|   24
  6    | Carlos |   4
  7    | Carlos |   4
  8    | Carlos |   28
  9    |  Jose  |   1
  10   |  Jose  |   2
  11   |  Jose  |   2
```

Removi os dados duplicados utilizando o comando:

```
colunas = ['Nome','Dia']

diaDuplicado = baseDados.drop_duplicates(subset = colunas)

diaDuplicado = diaDuplicado.reset_index()
```

Então, ficou:

```
 Index |  index  |  Nome  |  Dia
  0    |    0    | Pedro  |   3
  1    |    2    | Pedro  |   24
  2    |    3    | Antonio|   24
  3    |    6    | Carlos |   4
  4    |    8    | Carlos |   28
  5    |    9    |  Jose  |   1
  6    |    10   |  Jose  |   2
```

Agora minha dúvida.
Eu precisava agrupar os dias por nomes, para ficar desta maneira:

```
Index |  Nome  |  Dia
  0   | Pedro  |   3, 24
  1   | Antonio|   24
  2   | Carlos |   4, 28
  3   |  Jose  |   1, 2
```

Porém, a única solução que encontrei foi:

```
diasgroup = diaDuplicado.groupby(by=['Nome'])['Dia'].apply(list)
```

Mas dessa forma ele transforma a coluna "Nome" em indice e fica em um formato/Tipo "objeto".

```
Index  |  Dia
Pedro  |  3, 24
Antonio|  24
Carlos |  4, 28   
 Jose  |  1, 2
```

Algém conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: Usar um `diasgroup.reset_index()` não funcionaria?

Answer (score 7):

Utilizando a função `groupby`:

```
df[['Nome', 'Dia']].groupby('Nome').agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
Out[6]:
      Nome      Dia
0  Antonio     [24]
1   Carlos  [4, 28]
2     Jose   [1, 2]
3    Pedro  [24, 3] 
dtype: object
```

Comment: Rapaz, eu dei minha resposta, mas a tua tá muito melhor! upvote certeza :)

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-groupby)

> Editada
>   Relendo a questão vi que o autor da pergunta havia conseguido o que queria mas disse que o resultado é um objeto e que os nomes se tornam indices, ou algo parecido. Fiquei pensando se mesmo que ele possa "navegar" nesse objeto e jogar os elementos em uma lista, dicionário ou qq outra variável, não atenderia? Vou manter minha resposta original, para caso o requisito tenha que ser um `DataFrame` mas vou colocar abaixo o código para iterar no objeto que se obtem ao converter o `DataFrame` para lista, um `pandas.core.series.Series`, (vou utilizar o fragmento de codigo que ele utiliza na pergunta, para criar o objeto):

```
# Criando o pandas.core.series.Series
diasgroup = diaDuplicado.groupby(by=['Nome'])['Dia'].apply(list)

# Navegando em diasgroup
for i in diasgroup.items():
    print(i)
```

Saida:

```
('Antonio', [24])
('Carlos', [4, 28])
('Jose', [1, 2])
('Pedro', [3, 24])
```

**Daqui em diante é para o caso em que resultado precise ser um DataFrame:**

Não tenho certeza se o pandas apresenta os dados exatamente do jeito que vc quer no `groupby`, mas vc pode converter para um dataframe multindex vazio, que apresenta algo assim:

[image: Apresentação do df agrupado]

Estou apresentando a foto, porque quando só consigo essa saida, em um jupyter notebook quando digito o nome do `df`, sem a função `print`, com a função print, o resultado é esse:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(Antonio, 24), (Carlos, 4), (Carlos, 28), (Jose, 1), (Jose, 2), 
(Pedro, 3), (Pedro, 24)]
```

Veja que de qq forma da para vc navegar nos indices e extrair as informaçẽs que precisar.

Vamos ao código:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

s = '''
Nome,Dia
Pedro,3
Pedro,3
Pedro,24
Antonio,24
Antonio,24
Antonio,24
Carlos,4
Carlos,4
Carlos,28
Jose,1
Jose,2
Jose,2
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), parse_dates=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Nome','Dia'])

grouped = df.groupby(['Nome', 'Dia']).sum()

print(grouped)
```

Saída:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(Antonio, 24), (Carlos, 4), (Carlos, 28), (Jose, 1), (Jose, 2),
(Pedro, 3), (Pedro, 24)]
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta envolve alguns passos.

Criando o DataFrame já deduplicado:

```
import pandas as pd    
diaDuplicado = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Nome", "dia"], 
                 data=[["Pedro", 3], 
                       ["Pedro", 24], 
                       ["Antonio", 24], 
                       ["Carlos", 4], 
                       ["Carlos",28], 
                       ["Jose", 1], 
                       ["Jose", 2]])
```

O DataFrame:

```
print(diaDuplicado)
      Nome  dia
0    Pedro    3
1    Pedro   24
2  Antonio   24
3   Carlos    4
4   Carlos   28
5     Jose    1
6     Jose    2
```

Na sequência, gerando tuplas numa série. A razão de gerarmos tuplas (e não listas aqui) é que listas não são *hashable*, o que na prática implica que o Pandas não consegue deduplicar listas:

```
d = k.groupby(by=['Nome'])['dia'].apply(tuple)
```

O resultado fica:

```
Nome
Antonio      (24,)
Carlos     (4, 28)
Jose        (1, 2)
Pedro      (3, 24)
Name: dia, dtype: object
```

Mergeando os dois Dataframes pelas chaves corretas:

```
p = pd.merge(k, d, left_on="Nome", right_index=True)
print(p)

      Nome  dia_x    dia_y
0    Pedro      3  (3, 24)
1    Pedro     24  (3, 24)
2  Antonio     24    (24,)
3   Carlos      4  (4, 28)
4   Carlos     28  (4, 28)
5     Jose      1   (1, 2)
6     Jose      2   (1, 2)
```

Agora é só deduplicar novamente, considerando as colunas de interesse:

```
colunas = ['Nome','dia_y']
diaDuplicado = p.drop_duplicates(subset = colunas)
```

O que resulta no dataframe:

```
      Nome  dia_x    dia_y
 0    Pedro      3  (3, 24)
 2  Antonio     24    (24,)
 3   Carlos      4  (4, 28)
 5     Jose      1   (1, 2)
```

Agora basta convertar a coluna "dia_y" para lista e derrubar as coluna dia_x e dia_y:

```
diaDuplicado["DiaLista"] = diaDuplicado["dia_y"].apply(list)
diaLista=diaDuplicado.drop(["dia_x", "dia_y"], axis=1)
```

O que resulta no DataFrame "diaLista":

```
      Nome  DiaLista
0    Pedro   [3, 24]
2  Antonio      [24]
3   Carlos   [4, 28]
5     Jose    [1, 2]
```